# How to modify dns server in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, registry, dns, adapter

I want to change the primary dns server to some ip(e.g. 8.8.8.8), for all active adapters.

I tried to modify the registry, for all interfaces under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\Tcpip\\Parameters`, the `NameServer` is changed to what i want.

However it doesn't work. `ipconfig /all` shows that the dns is changed, however the system seems didn't apply that. If I open the attribute of `TCP/IPv4`, the dns is already changed, then i click `OK`, until now the dns is put into use.

Could someone tell me how to solve this? you may go some other ways, besides registry.

Update: what i did will finally apply, after about 6~8 mins.

Comment: Have you searched the registry for more copies of the name server address? It may be cached somewhere else, either in registry or in memory, or both.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg right, it may be loaded into memory, if so, do you know how to refresh it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for if someone need this, finally I used `ipconfig /registerdns` to refresh dns config in registry.